# compare 2 list of dicts containing different keys and update if match found

Tags: python-3.x

I have two list of dictionaries containing different keys. I know the keys that I want to compare. If there is a match in their values, I want to update the dict, from the list, been compared with the value of a key from the matching dict in the second list of dicts. I need to compare multiple keys at a time. Note: the number of items in each dict and dicts in each list are much longer than what I have in my example

```
list1 = [{'c':4, 'd':'er3', 'e':'egg'}, {'c':1, 'd':'room1', 'e':'soup'}, {'c':a8, 'd':'er5', 'e':'rice'}]
list2 = [{'s':4, 'loc':'sw', food:'soup', t:'9pm'}, {'s':2, 'loc':'er5', food:'egg', t:'12am'}, {'s':1, 'loc':'se', food:'soup', t:'4pm'}, {'s':a7, 'loc':'n', food:'unknown', t:'1am'}]
```

desired result

```
result = [{'c':4, 'd':'er3', 'e':'egg', 'time':'NA'}, {'c':1, 'd':'room1', 'e':'soup', time:'4pm'}, {'c':a8, 'd':'er5', 'e':'rice', 'time':'NA'}}
```

I compared dict keys c and s and keys e and food. In this case only the second dict in list1 matched so I updated the matched dict with a key time and inserted the value of key t from the dict. For the non matched dict, I still entered a key time but set it to NA.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for mydict in list1:
    mydict['time'] = [x.get('t') for x in list2 if any([x.get('s') == mydict.get('c') and x.get('food')== mydict.get('e') for x in list2])]
    print(mydict)
```

when I print, I get the result but with multiple NA's like this:

```
{'c':1, 'd':'room1', 'e':'soup', time: ['4pm', 'NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA'}
```

Any help will be appreciated. How do I format the long blocks to avoid scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I can not post comments so I will post an answer. Your code has several errors, please check it. There are several undefined variables like `e`, `time`, etc when you define the lists. You must put those between `''`.

Then you call a dictionary when you say `mydict('e')`, but the class is not callable. `mydict.get('e')` will work.

With those changes, I get the result:

```
{'c': 4, 'd': 'er3', 'e': 'egg', 'time': []}
{'c': 1, 'd': 'room1', 'e': 'soup', 'time': ['9pm', '12am', '4pm', '1am']}
{'c': 'a8', 'd': 'er5', 'e': 'rice', 'time': []}
```

Comment: I understand. that was an error on my part. So what I wanted was to have just one value rather than all the values. and where I had empty lists, I wanted those to be NA's e.g {'c': 1, 'd': 'room1', 'e': 'soup', 'time': ['9pm', '12am', '4pm', '1am']} should be something like {'c': 1, 'd': 'room1', 'e': 'soup', 'time': '4pm'} and {'c': 4, 'd': 'er3', 'e': 'egg', 'time': []} should be {'c': 4, 'd': 'er3', 'e': 'egg', 'time': 'NA'}